# Showing zeros of polynomials using diamond and circle shapes

Tags: plotting

I want to depict zeros of various polynomials with arbitrarily chosen shapes. Currently, I can show all the zeros using a circular shape, but I am trying to use diamonds and a circle.

My code(s) is shown below:

```
zero1001={z,0}/.NSolve[(z-0.5) (z-1.2) (z-1.7) (z-2.5)==0,z,Reals];
zero1002={z,0}/.NSolve[(z-1.4)==0,z,Reals];
zero1003={z,0}/.NSolve[(z-1.9)==0,z,Reals];
zero1004={z,0}/.NSolve[(z-2.3)==0,z,Reals];
Plot[{(z-0.5) (z-1.2) (z-1.7) (z-2.5),(z-1.4),(z-1.9),(z-2.3)},{z,-0.5,3.0}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Hue[0.67,0.6,0.6], Opacity[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.]], 
Epilog -> {{Blue, PointSize[0.011], Point[zero1001]}, {Pink, PointSize[0.011], Point[zero1002]}, 
{Green, PointSize[0.011], Point[zero1003]}, {Orange, PointSize[0.011], Point[zero1004]}}, 
PlotRange -> 0.005, PlotLabel -> Style["Graphical illustration of zeros of polynomials", FontSize -> 15]]
```

The output is:

[image]

I want the `Pink`, `Green` and `Orange` circles as diamonds. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use `PlotMarkers`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p1 = (z - 0.5) (z - 1.2) (z - 1.7) (z - 2.5);
p2 = (z - 1.4);
p3 = (z - 1.9);
p4 = (z - 2.3);

zero1001 = {z, 0} /. NSolve[p1 == 0, z, Reals];
zero1002 = {z, 0} /. NSolve[p2 == 0, z, Reals];
zero1003 = {z, 0} /. NSolve[p3 == 0, z, Reals];
zero1004 = {z, 0} /. NSolve[p4 == 0, z, Reals];

Plot[{p1, p2, p3, p4}
 , {z, -0.5, 3.0}
 , PlotStyle -> (Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[2]] & /@ {Blue, Pink, 
     Green, Orange})
 , Epilog -> {
   {Text[Style["\[FilledCircle]", Blue, 10], #] & /@ zero1001}
   , {Text[Style["\[FilledDiamond]", Pink, 12], #] & /@ zero1002}
   , {Text[Style["\[FilledDiamond]", Green, 12], #] & /@ zero1003}
   , {Text[Style["\[FilledDiamond]", Orange, 12], #] & /@ zero1004}
   }
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , AspectRatio -> 1/6
 , PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 3.0}, {-0.3, 0.3}}
 , PlotLabel -> Style["Graphical illustration of zeros of polynomials"
   , FontSize -> 15]
 ]
```

[image]

---

**Using `PlotMarkers`:**

```
cols = {Blue, Pink, Green, Orange};
plt1 = Plot[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, {z, -0.5, 3.0}
   , PlotStyle -> (Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[2]] & /@ cols)
   , PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 3.0}, {-0.3, 0.3}}
   , AspectRatio -> 1/4
   ];
plt2 = ListPlot[{zero1001, zero1002, zero1003, zero1004}
   , PlotStyle -> cols
   , PlotMarkers -> {{"\[EmptyCircle]", 15}, {"\[EmptyDiamond]", 
      15}, {"\[FilledDiamond]", 15}, {"\[EmptySquare]", 15}}
   ];
Show[plt1, plt2]
```

[image]

Comment: You can try other shapes; e.g.: `{Text[Style["\[EmptyCircle]", Blue, 15], #] & /@ zero1001}` etc and remove the curves if needed.

Comment: Thank you, Syed, for the code. This is amazing. I got to know a lot from this.

Comment: When I save it as .png or .jpg, I get an image with less resolution. Can we have some code(s) to get a high-resolution image (.png or .jpg) of this graph?

Comment: You can start a fresh post and include details (and perhaps a screenshot) there. It is a good idea to search the Q/As on the forum.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.